# Не могу подключить свой шрифт через @font-face

Tags: html, шрифты

Всем привет не могу подключить свой шрифт, проверяю в двух браузерах и не в одном не работает. Закинул Шрифт в корневую папку. Ниже приведен код:

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: MyCustomFont;
  src: url(OpenSans-Light.ttf) /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
 }
 body,html {
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-left:0px;
 margin-right::0px;
 margin-bottom:0px; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align:top;
 vertical-align:top;
 font-size:12px;
 font-family:"MyCustomFont";
 color:#ffffff;
 background-image:url(../img/bg.jpg);
 background-repeat:repeat-y;
 background-color:#c5c5c5;
 background-position:50% 0;
 }
```

В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/khpZU/

Comment: заработало,как описано здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/645639/228324 спасибо

Comment: Поробуйте подключить cyrillic вариант, для русского языка

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться онлайн-генераторами шрифтов, чтобы сгенерировать шрифты разных форматов под разные браузеры:

```
1) http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
2) http://www.web-font-generator.com/
```

Загрузите свой шрифт, в ответ вам будет дан на скачивание архив с различными форматами и CSS-файл с необходимым кодом. Скопируйте скаченные щрифты к себе на сайт и вставьте CSS. Попробуйте оба генератора, не знаю почему, но работают они, видимо, по-разному. В случае использования первого сервиса, выберете "**EXPERT...**" и добавьте SVG формат, если не ошибаюсь, он нужен для Firefox. Не забудьте проверить корректность путей до шрифтов.

Answer (score 2):

Не работал когда шрифт в отдельной папке лежал (путь указан корректно). Переложила в CSS - заработало!
На habrahabr.ru вычитала: "не будут подключаться шрифты с правильными путями в CSS, но когда сам файл CSS подключается в HTML вверх по дереву папок... Причина этому политика безопасности браузера... Локальные документы имеют доступ к другим локальным документы в том же каталоге и в подкаталогах, но не в верхних разделах. (По умолчанию)..."

Answer (score 1):

Было до этого и **не работало**:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: Proxima;
        font-weight: normal;
        src: url(./fonts/proxima-normal.otf);
    }
```

Добавил **апострофы** в *font-family*:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Proxima';
        font-weight: normal;
        src: url(./fonts/proxima-normal.otf);
    }
```

А в селекторе уже без **апострофов**:

```
    .greeting {
        color: white;
        font-family: Proxima;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
```

***И все заработало!***

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте с кавычками

```
font-family:'MyCustomFont';
src: url('OpenSans-Light.ttf');
```

Answer (score 0):

Берите web font, woff, а не ttf. Тогда все сядет на свои места ;)

А еще, советую работать с Google Fonts. Это куда проще и легче:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

На примере взят класс Dosis. Выберите свой и все. Зачем Вам лишние строчки?

Answer (score 0):

Сам парился с этой проблемой.
Было:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  src: local("Open Sans"),
       url("../fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Убрал второй шрифт sans-serif, поменял кавычки на апострофы.
Стало:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: local('Open Sans'),
       url('../fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf');
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Так заработал.

Answer (score 0):

А если путь указать из корневого каталога, где и поместить локально гарнитуры этих шрифтов? Вот так они у меня определились:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'franklingothic-book';
src: url('/franklingothic-book-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/franklingothic-book-webfont.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
* {
font-family: franklingothic-book;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Не хватает точки с запятой после `src: url(OpenSans-Light.ttf)`

Comment: В css допускается не ставить `;` перед `}`.